# Where is continuity needed in this problem?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $(0,1]$, where $\liminf_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \alpha$ and $\limsup_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \beta$. Prove that for any $\xi \in [\alpha, \beta]$, there is $\{ x_n\} \in (0, 1]$ so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \xi$.

Here is how I thought about this problem.

First, let $\beta - \alpha = l$, and fix $\xi$. Let $\epsilon_1 = l/2$, and consider a neighborhood $U_1$ of $\xi$. Clearly there is $x_1 \in (0,1]$ so that $f(x_1) \in U_1$. We construct the tail of the sequence inductively. In fact, if $\xi \neq \alpha$, we can even construct the sequence from below.

Suppose that $x_k$ has been constructed. To construct $x_{k+1}$, let $\epsilon_{k+1} = \frac{l}{2^{k+2}}$, and consider $U_{k+1}$ a neighborhood of width $\epsilon_{k+1}$ about $\xi$. Now by the definition of $\limsup$, we may find points mapped into the interval $[f(x_k), \xi]$ in the interval $(0, x_{k})$, since $\xi \leq \beta$ and $\beta$ is the limit supremum. So we can find such a point $x_{k+1}$ mapping into $U_{k+1}$ as desired.

Now since the $U_i$ are a descending sequence of nested intervals, where $\bar{U_i} \subset U_{i-1}$ for every $i$, it follows from the nested interval theorem that the intersection of all of these sets is a singleton, namely $\{ \xi \}$. So $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \xi$.

Something's wrong here, but I can't catch it. Or I am using continuity in some way I have not noticed.

Comment: The first time you use continuity is at "Clearly there is $x_1\in(0,1]$ so that $f(x_1)\in U_1$." With $f(x)={\bf 1}_{\Bbb Q}$, $\alpha=0$, $\beta=1$, $\xi=\frac12$, you choose $\epsilon_1=\frac 12$ and $U_1=(0,1)$. But $f(x)\notin(0,1)$ for all $x$.

Comment: What you actually need is the intermediate value property.

Comment: Oh! So foolish of me. I should turn my degree in. Thank you. I am using the intermediate value theorem to produce the $x_k$ at each step.

Comment: BTW, does the problem not require that $x_n\to 0$? If not, for all $\xi\in(\alpha,\beta)$, finding a single $x$ with $f(x)=\xi$ is possible and sufficient.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I noticed this also, but didn't think anything of it. Since it's an old exam, I just figured someone would have pointed that out and corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To construct $x_{k+1}$, let $\epsilon_{k+1} = \frac{l}{2^{k+2}}$, and consider $U_{k+1}$ a neighborhood of width $\epsilon_{k+1}$ about $\xi$. Now by the definition of $\limsup$, we may find points mapped into the interval $[f(x_k), \xi]$ in the interval $(0, x_{k})$, since $\xi \leq \beta$ and $\beta$ is the limit supremum.

No -- the definition of limsup just says you can find something that maps into the interval $[\beta-\epsilon,\beta+\epsilon]$, but what it maps into may well be much larger than $\xi$ and in particular outside your $U_{k+1}$.

What you need if that happens is the **intermediate value theorem** to show that the function value has passed through $U_{k+1}$ on its way up to the point you got from the limsup. And this depends on continuity.

---

For an actually rigorous solution, I think it is easiest to divide into the cases $\xi=\alpha$, $\xi=\beta$ and $\alpha<\xi<\beta$. The first two of these cases follow directly from the definitions of liminf or limsup separately; for the last you can construct each $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)=\xi$ exactly; all you then need is to make sure that $x_n\to 0$ (which, as Hagen noticed, the problem statement accidentally failed to require).

Answer (score 0):

Without continuity, a counter-example can be easily constructed as
follows:

Let $\alpha<\beta$. Define $f:(0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\begin{cases}
\alpha, & \mbox{ if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
\beta, & \mbox{ if }x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}.$

We need the intermediate value property for $f$, which follows from
continuity.